# Set user to require SSL in mariaDB does not force connection to use certificate

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb, xampp, mysql-workbench

My localhost is running MariaDB 10.6.7 on Win64.

I am trying to force SSL when connecting to MariaDB.
I test the connection using MySQL Workbench 8.0.

To enable the SSL, I did the following:

1. I generate self signed certificate, then in my.ini, I set the following:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/xampp/MariaDB 10.6/data

port=3306

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1009M

ssl-ca=C:/xampp/xampp/certs/mysql/ca-cert.pem

ssl-cert=C:/xampp/xampp/certs/mysql/server-cert.pem

ssl-key=C:/xampp/xampp/certs/mysql/server-key.pem

[client]

port=3306

plugin-dir=C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.6/lib/plugin

ssl-ca=C:/xampp/xampp/certs/mysql/ca-cert.pem

ssl-cert=C:/xampp/xampp/certs/mysql/client-cert.pem

ssl-key=C:/xampp/xampp/certs/mysql/client-key.pem
```

2. To force SSL, I set the user in MariaDB to require SSL.

Unfortunately, with this configuration, I **can still connect** to MySQL **without** using any certificate. How can I force MariaDB to force SSL or FAIL?

My second question, I have a suspicion that my configuration is actually for setting using Require X509. Is this the case? If yes, how can I set it up to just use Require SSL?

Last, having the certificate set in my.ini, prevent me from connecting to mysql via the regular way, that is: mysql -u root. I got the following error:

```
 ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: An unknown error occurred while processing 
 the certificate. Error 0x80090327(SEC_E_CERT_UNKNOWN).
```

I have tried to use the following command, mysql --ssl-ca=[directory]\client-cert.pem -u root, without success. I got the same error as above. Any idea?

If you have a reference page or any kind of insight, that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my test in Win64, the ssl-ca, ssl-cert, ssl-key under [client] is not required for "Require SSL". This settings were also the reason why I could not login using "mysql -u root".

I use MySQL Workbench to test my connection to MariaDB. From my testing, even though I did not provide any certificate, as long as the server have certificate for SSL, then the connection would be encrypted (Require SSL). Having said that, I did try to provide a ca-cert.pem, but it did not work. From my research in google, it seems that this may due to the SSL Library used in MariaDB. The SSL library may be different for different distribution.

As for the X509, I was able to get it working in Linux. I did this once and was not doing further testing since I am working in windows at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a user, you need to add the require parameter, which can be x509 or ssl.

take for example

create user itpuxs2@'%' identified by 'root' require x509;

create user itpuxs3@'%' identified by 'root' require ssl;

Comment: I mentioned in step #2. I set set the user to use Require SSL.

Comment: mysql -uitpuxs3 -p --ssl-ca=/mysql/data/3306/ca.pem --ssl-cert=/mysql/data/3306/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/mysql/data/3306/client-key.pem
@Lukas

Comment: Still got the same error as mentioned previously

Comment: show variables like '%ssl_mode%';    vi my.cnf ssl_mode=REQUIRED

Answer (score 1):

For the requirement "login should require a valid client certificate pair, or else the connection should fail", you should create a MariaDB user using "REQUIRE X509" rather than "REQUIRE SSL".

**REQUIRE SSL** means one-way TLS authentication: the MariaDB client must verify that the server's certificate is signed by a certificate authority it trusts. No client certificate is required. All traffic is fully encrypted.

**REQUIRE X509** means two-way TLS (mutual authentication): in addition to the above, the MariaDB server must also trust the certificate authority that signed the client's certificate.

Both methods fully encrypt database traffic. The second strategy prevents a connection from someone who has the password but not a trusted certificate from connecting.

Refer to
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/#requiring-tls-for-specific-user-accounts